# JayData with WebAPI and OData doesn't run callback

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, jaydata

I'm using the latest version of JayData with the RC for Asp.Net WebAPI OData. When I run the JavaScript function to fetch data from the server, I can see the request and response with JSON data. However, the .then() function never fires so the UI is unaware that data was returned from the server.

Here is my JayData call:

```
(function(root) {
    var context = new Default.Container({
        name: 'oData',
        oDataServiceHost: '../api/transactions'
    });

    $(function() {
        context.TransactionsByMonth.take(5).toArray().then(function(transactions) {
            transactions.forEach(function (transaction) {
                alert('Test');
            });
        });
    });
}(window));
```

Here are the response headers:

Response Headers
Cache-Control   no-cache
Content-Length  1811
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Fri, 21 Dec 2012 08:32:58 GMT
Expires -1
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles   =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcanVzdGluXGRvY3VtZW50c1x2aXN1YWwgc3R1ZGlvIDIwMTJcUHJvamVjdHNcVHJlYXNTdXJlLldlYlxUcmVhc1N1cmUuV2ViXGFwaVx0cmFuc2FjdGlvbnNcVHJhbnNhY3Rpb25zQnlNb250aA==?=
Request Headers
Accept  application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=verbose;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  glimpseState=null; glimpseLatestVersion=0.87; glimpseOptions=null; glimpseClientName=null
Host    localhost:42039
MaxDataServiceVersion   2.0
Referer http://{localhost}/dashboard/test
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0

Here is the response:

```
[
  {
    "TransactionByMonthId": 1,
    "BeginningBalanceAmount": 5970.0,
    "FloatAmount": 8027.0,
    "InflowsAmount": 8607.0,
    "OutflowsAmount": -2057.0,
    "EndingBalanceAmount": 33345.0,
    "MonthOfYear": 12,
    "MonthOfYearName": "MonthOfYearName6136f9ba-95c3-4977-ab29-5ec2e2968c5f",
    "QuarterOfYear": 8,
    "YearNumber": 2012
  },
  {
    "TransactionByMonthId": 10,
    "BeginningBalanceAmount": 9201.0,
    "FloatAmount": 4723.0,
    "InflowsAmount": 4933.0,
    "OutflowsAmount": -2808.0,
    "EndingBalanceAmount": 9858.0,
    "MonthOfYear": 11,
    "MonthOfYearName": "MonthOfYearName7c407e0d-d730-43c3-aff6-d3e56313f992",
    "QuarterOfYear": 17,
    "YearNumber": 2012
  },
  {
    "TransactionByMonthId": 19,
    "BeginningBalanceAmount": 3151.0,
    "FloatAmount": 19.0,
    "InflowsAmount": 9340.0,
    "OutflowsAmount": -6118.0,
    "EndingBalanceAmount": 19958.0,
    "MonthOfYear": 10,
    "MonthOfYearName": "MonthOfYearName504ded96-a4e3-4492-ae22-98da7c9c2ba1",
    "QuarterOfYear": 26,
    "YearNumber": 2012
  },
  {
    "TransactionByMonthId": 28,
    "BeginningBalanceAmount": 3826.0,
    "FloatAmount": 7120.0,
    "InflowsAmount": 3341.0,
    "OutflowsAmount": -9360.0,
    "EndingBalanceAmount": 33617.0,
    "MonthOfYear": 9,
    "MonthOfYearName": "MonthOfYearName5fa907a3-b6a3-4a42-a53b-2229da6e1dc6",
    "QuarterOfYear": 35,
    "YearNumber": 2012
  },
  {
    "TransactionByMonthId": 37,
    "BeginningBalanceAmount": 6832.0,
    "FloatAmount": 4412.0,
    "InflowsAmount": 2462.0,
    "OutflowsAmount": -3726.0,
    "EndingBalanceAmount": 40857.0,
    "MonthOfYear": 8,
    "MonthOfYearName": "MonthOfYearNameb3f6a899-6201-418a-b020-31babb42123b",
    "QuarterOfYear": 44,
    "YearNumber": 2012
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that should be checked:

**jquery or q required**

If you want to use the promise interfaces (then/fail),then you should include jquery or q.js as a promise implementation (JayData does not have an own promise implementation). If you use q.js you also have to include jaydatamodules/qdeferred.js as promise adapter (this you don't have to do with jquery).

**Given response is WebAPI not OData**

The response payload you copied is not OData, it must be coming from a  simple WebAPI response. So you need the WebAPI provider from JayData instead of the OData provider with this format. If you are using the ASP.NET WebAPI OData package then something is not correctly wired in: this package changes the WebAPI response payload format to that of that OData.

Answer (score 0):

Please catch and log the fail branch too.
.then()
.fail(function(reason){console.log(reason);})
Also with chrome you can catch if any exception occurs so please try that also.

Comment: Now I can see from the headers that you use firefox. Please be sure to use our patched datajs.

Comment: Please also note that we released a new version yesterday with which you can use webapi without odata, but of course you can also use it with odata, too. More info: jaydata.org/blog

Comment: This doesn't appear to be JayData specific. It has something to do with WebApi OData formatters.

Comment: Try to use map() so the server only returns a few fields, this way you have a chance to find out which field causes the problem.